# Bit Bucket API - can you transfer a repository

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to transfer a repository via the bitbucket rest api (v1 or v2)?

Specifically, this functionality:

https://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/06/13/transfer-repositories/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible, but have been requested since 2012: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5333/change-repository-ownership-through-the